# Unable to find Apache HTTP Server 2.4 binary for windows

Tags: windows, http, binary, server

I am trying to download the latest version of Apache HTTP server 2.4.x.
I am looking at Apache HTTP server page it takes me to the following page.

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/

I see no binary file for windows. I also looked at archived folder and I am seeing that 2.2.9 is the most recent version. Any ideas as where I can download it?

Answer (score 3):

there are some links for binary downloads here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#down

Answer (score 0):

Well, not anymore:

"The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software, only source code. Individual committers may provide binary packages as a convenience, but it is not a release deliverable.

If you cannot compile the Apache HTTP Server yourself, you can obtain a binary package from numerous binary distributions available on the Internet."

Comment: This seems to be a reply to another answer.